# python socket error string handling

Tags: python, sockets

this is my server code i am getting error while sending a string from server to client please help me to fix this i am a new to socket programming.i had never done any networking before.right now i am learning python so as a part of python programming i am learning so please teach me how to fix this error

```
            import socket
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            host = socket.gethostname()
            port = 8899
            s.bind((host,port))
            s.listen(5)
            while True:
                    c,a=s.accept()

                    c.send("bruce"%a)
                    c.close()
```

this is my client code

```
                     import socket
                     s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                     host = socket.gethostname()
                     port =8899
                     s.connect((host,port))
                     s.recv(1034)
                     s.close()
```

this is my error

```
                    Traceback (most recent call last):
                    File "s.py", line 10, in <module>
                    c.send("bruce"%a[1])
                    TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: what is the value of a[1]?

Comment: This has NOTHING to do with socket programming!  ``"bruce"%a`` is simply an invalid operation.  To perform string formatting via the ``%`` operation, you have to put format codes into the string to specify the position and type of the values to be inserted.  For example, ``"bruce %s" % a`` would format ``a`` as a string, at the end of the resulting string.

Comment: thank you it helped me to figure out my error thank you for fixing my code